# What is the difference between the Mantis bug severities Crash and Block?

Tags: testing, bug-tracking, mantis

I want to know the difference between the severities Crash and Block with some examples. When will each be used? Also, what is Tweak?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The various severities are not interpreted by MantisBT. You should use them as you see fit.

Comment: @Pacerier - precisely, there is no intended usage :-)